# How to disable sliding cart in Woocommerce Shoptimizer in mobile?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm encountering an issue with the sliding cart drawer every time I add a new item to the cart. I'm currently using the Shoptimizer theme for WooCommerce.

While I've noticed there's an option in the settings to disable it (https://www.commercegurus.com/docs/shoptimizer-theme/disable-slide-out-cart/), the problem is that it completely disables it. My preference is to only disable it on mobile view while retaining the AJAX add item function.

Is there a way to achieve this?